# Schema First .NET Graphql not resolving MVE

Tags: schema, .net-7.0, asp.net-core-7.0, graphql.net

Running ASP.NET Core 7.0. & GraphQL 7.6.1.

I'm trying to create a minimum viable example of schema first GraphQL with GraphQL.NET, but query is not resolving. The GraphQL resolves in the console, but not in the API, so likely a DI problem...

I keep getting a message

> Error trying to resolve field 'user'

**Schema**

```
type Query {
  user: User
}

type User {
  id: String!
  name: String!
}
```

**User.cs**

```
public class User
{
    public string Id { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    public string Name { get; set; } = string.Empty;
}

public class Query
{
    [GraphQLMetadata("user")]
    public User GetUser()
    {
        return new User { Id = "1", Name = "Simpleton" };
    }
}
```

**Program.cs**

```
// Get the schema information 
FileInfo fileInfo = new(Path.Join(AppContext.BaseDirectory, "schema.gql"));
var schemaText = await GetSchema(fileInfo);
var schema = Schema.For(schemaText,
  sb =>
  {
      sb.Types.Include<Query>();
  });

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
builder.Services.AddGraphQL(b => b
    .AddSchema(schema)  // schema
    .AddSystemTextJson());  // serializer

builder.Services.AddSingleton<IDataService, DataService>();
builder.Services.AddLogging(b => b.AddConsole());

var app = builder.Build();

if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
    app.UseGraphQLPlayground();
}

app.UseGraphQL("/graphql");  // url to host GraphQL endpoint

await app.RunAsync();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple fix, just needed to register the attributed Query class as a service:

```
builder.Services.AddSingleton<Query>();
```